# Inaccuracy of DATEDIFF in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To me, this looks pretty rough.  Maybe it has something to do with floating-point numbers, maybe not, but I don't think these really count well enough as edge cases to justify this:

```
select datediff(s, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:55.998') -- 0
select datediff(s, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:55.999') -- 1
select datediff(ms, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:57.229') -- 2000
select datediff(ms, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:57.230') -- 2000
```

This doesn't look like legitimate rounding at all.  Take the first two cases, for instance.  The seconds part remains the same, so it can't just be looking at that and ignoring the milliseconds.  But at the same time, the difference in milliseconds is a matter of `768` vs. `769`, not `499` vs. `500`.  And the last two cases don't even leave any room for rounding, yet SQL just sort of "coughs up" the idea that the difference in milliseconds is the same.  Finally, whereas the first two cases are closing in on the next second in terms of time on the clock, the last two cases are only closing in on the next second in terms of time that has expired.

Could somebody please explain how I could ever trust `DATEDIFF()` again after this?

Comment: I am getting 3rd select `select datediff(ms, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:57.229') -- 1999` please modofy the question.

Comment: what version you are running. i have tested on the MSSQL server 2012.

Comment: It's the same here.  MSSQL Server 2012.

Comment: I get results of 0, 0, 1999, 2000 on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Datediff "Returns the **count** (signed integer) of the specified datepart **boundaries crossed** between the specified startdate and enddate." Emphasis added. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx. And .999 will round up to the next second.

Comment: It's not datediff you shouldn't trust (well, once you read the documentation thoroughly), it's datetime. If you want better accuracy, pretty simple: use datetime2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are examples of the [built in accuracy restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  `datetime` rounds to the nearest .000, .003, or .007 seconds.

`datetime2` has [increased accuracy of 100 nanoseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx), but the system can still treat values below that accuracy threshold as the same value.

Try running these:

```
select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.998' as datetime) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.997' as datetime) --1

select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.998' as datetime) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.999' as datetime) --no results

select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:57.229' as datetime) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:57.230' as datetime) --1

select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.998' as datetime2) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.997' as datetime2) --no results

select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.998' as datetime2) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:55.999' as datetime2) --no results

select 1 where cast('2014-10-28 13:54:57.229' as datetime2) = cast('2014-10-28 13:54:57.230' as datetime2) --no results
```

Answer (score 0):

The datepart is important as in the following:

```
select datediff(s, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:55.998')--0
select datediff(ms, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:55.998') -- 768
select datediff(ms, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:57.230')--2000
select datediff(mcs, '2014-10-28 13:54:55.230', '2014-10-28 13:54:57.230')--2000000
```